# How can I write SQL code aggregate the table in a to b

Tags: sql

Table a has the structure like

```
EMP_ID  DATE_OF_PURCHASE    ITEM_PURCHASED  
------------------------------------------
1       01-JAN-19           BAG
2       01-JAN-19           UMBRELLA
1       03-JAN-19           UMBRELLA
3       01-JAN-19           PERFUME
1       04-JAN-19           PERFUME
```

and I would like to aggregate this to table b which looks like

```
EMP_ID  BAG     UMBRELLA    PERFUME
------------------------------------
1       YES     YES         YES
2       NO      YES         NO  
3       NO      NO          YES
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select emp_id,
       max(case when item_purchased = 'BAG' then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as BAG,
       max(case when item_purchased = 'UMBRELLA' then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as UMBRELLA,
       max(case when item_purchased = 'PERFUME' then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as PERFUME
from t
group by emp_id;
```

Your date format suggests Oracle.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3eb1195bf2fc5337cd5016316b3d343e) is a db<>fiddle that illustrates this working.

Comment: Thank you for helping me but it returns NO on the three columns and for all cases that means for all item buyers and  for one item buyer

Comment: Can you set up a db<>fiddle or something similar?  This would suggest either a very arcane collation where `'YES' < 'NO'` (I don't even know if one exists) or you `item_purchased` values are not exactly what you have shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select emp_id,
case when BAG = 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end as BAG,
case when UMBRELLA = 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end as UMBRELLA,
case when PERFUME = 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end as PERFUME
FROM
(select emp_id,
       max(case when item_purchased = 'BAG' then 1 else 0 end) as BAG,
       max(case when item_purchased = 'UMBRELLA' then 1 else 0 end) as UMBRELLA,
       max(case when item_purchased = 'PERFUME' then 1 else 0 end) as PERFUME
from t
group by emp_id);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: question hasn't been tagged by Oracle,while `decode` is spesific to it.